# Is there any way to force open down a pcalendar on modal

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have a p-dialog with a p-calendar. The problem is that when I try to open the calendar, it's open upwards. I wanna open downwards.

```
<p-dialog responsive="true" modal="true" (onHide)="closeDialog()" #genericDialog 
   [(visible)]="displayModal"
   class="generic-dialog">

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'DATE_CUSTOM'" class="form-group form-control-head"
    [class.has-success]="formGroup.controls ? formGroup.controls[control.name].valid : false">
    <p-calendar [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" 
                [showTime]="false"
                [minDate]="dateMin" [maxDate]="dateMax" yearRange="2000:2030" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
                [showIcon]="true"
                [style]="{'width': '95%'}" [inputStyle]="{'height': 'calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 4px)', 
                'width': '100%'}"
                [formControlName]="control.name" [showButtonBar]="true" [locale]="calendarLang">
    </p-calendar>
  </div>
   <br>
  <p-footer>
     <div class="col-12 text-center mb-4">
        <button [disabled]="formGroup.invalid" (click)="submit()"
         class="btn btn-primary px-4">Save
         </button>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info px-4" (click)="closeDialog()"
             style="color: white">Cancel
       </button>
    </div>
  </p-footer>

</p-dialog>
```

Comment: Could you please create a stackblitz?

Comment: mmh now I can't.. sorry

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue, a long time back. I would say directly you can't force p-calendar to open downward or upward.

Because It depends on the space available on the upward and downward of the input box of p-calendar.

So, to manually open on upward direction, keep enough space on an upward direction and less space in a downward direction from the input box.

That way you can achieve, hope it helps!

Comment: oh that's bad.. ok thank you for the suggestions and your experience!!